# How to replicate the behavior of the 3 android physical buttons in code

Tags: android

How could I replicate in code the same (not similar) effect of the pressure of a specific physical button of the device for each of the 3 standard physical keys

-MENU
-BACK
-HOME

Is there a way to invoke the same OS listeners?

Comment: You want to simulate these button presses?

Comment: no, I want know how invoke the same listener that the OS invoke when you press each of these buttons